# Add members to an existing conversation

Tags: botframework

(New to Bot Framework)(Using botbuilder SDK4) I have a requirement of passing the control to an agent in case the bot does not recognise the intent of the phrase entered by the customer. I want to connect the customer and the agent using the bot. In my current attempt to achieve this, I am using `adapter.continueConversation(conversationReference, logic)`

But then I realised, there is an entity called members in the conversation (there exists a method `getConversationMembers` in `botframework-connector/lib/connectorApi/operations/conversations.d.ts`).

Question 1: Can I use this attribute for the aforementioned use case?

Question 2: How to add multiple members in a conversation?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a custom middleware is the most efficient way to handover a conversation from the bot to an agent. [Here](https://github.com/tdurnford/botframework-human-handoff) is an example of a bot that implements middleware to forward messages between users and agents with proactive messages. The example uses an array based handover provider to save the state of every conversation. You should implement your own provider with a database structure to fit your project requirements.

Hope this helps.